# How does ReadableByteChannelImpl handle interrupts

Tags: java

I'm attempting to use `Channels.newChannel` to wrap an InputStream in order to support interrupts. I've seen conflicting information whether this will work. Including the comment in ReadableByteChannelImpl: `// Not really interruptible`

In `ReadableByteChannelImpl`, before making the the blocking call into `InputStream.read`, `AbstractInterruptibleChannel.begin` is called which sets up an new `Interruptible` using `sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().blockedOn` which will close the wrapped InputStream.

```
protected final void begin() {
    if (interruptor == null) {
        interruptor = new Interruptible() {
                public void interrupt(Thread target) {
                    synchronized (closeLock) {
                        if (!open)
                            return;
                        open = false;
                        interrupted = target;
                        try {
                            AbstractInterruptibleChannel.this.implCloseChannel();
                        } catch (IOException x) { }
                    }
                }};
    }
    blockedOn(interruptor);
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
    if (me.isInterrupted())
        interruptor.interrupt(me);
}
```

Is it true that if an `InputStream` will throw an `IOException` from a blocked read call if it is closed by another thread then `ReadableByteChannelImpl` will make the wrapped stream interruptible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pretty much. The `Channels.newChannel()` adapter returns a `ReadableByteChannelImpl` instance unless the stream is a `FileInputStream`; in that case, it returns a `FileChannel`, which is also interruptible.

When you do get a `ReadableByteChannel`, the code you've already examined suggests (and testing confirms) that the underlying `InputStream` is closed asynchronously by an `interrupt()` on the thread blocked in a read.

It can depend on the implementation of the `InputStream`, but implementations included in the core Java runtime will respond to asynchronous closure by throwing an exception in the reading thread. The specific type of exception will vary.